# Incomplete \iffalse when using datetime package and \write

Tags: datetime, write

## Objective

A function that enables me to write custom log data.
The result is the command `\writeToLog` (see MWE), which writes its input to the file `log.txt`.

## Issue

In my actual document I'm using the package `datetime`.
If I comment out `\usepackage{datetime}`, the compilation works fine.
If it's not commented out, I get the error

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 15.
```

Why does this happen and what is the solution?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{datetime}

% Creates a file called log.txt
\newwrite\logFile
\immediate\openout\logFile=log.txt
\newcommand{\writeToLog}[1]{
    \immediate\write\logFile{#1}
}
\AtEndDocument{
    \immediate\closeout\logFile
}

% I'd like to log the compilation date, among other things
\writeToLog{Compiled on \today}

\begin{document}

Content

\end{document}
```

## Edit

I also tried using `datetime2` with the MWE below, but this writes

```
Compiled on 9\, \DTMmonthname {11} 2022
```

How do I make sure that it outputs `Compiled on 9 November 2022`?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}

% Set date format
\DTMnewdatestyle{mydateformat}{%
  \renewcommand{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{%
    \number##3\, \DTMmonthname{##2} \number##1%
  }%
  \renewcommand{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
}
\DTMsetdatestyle{mydateformat}

% Creates a file called log.txt
\newwrite\logFile
\immediate\openout\logFile=log.txt
\newcommand{\writeToLog}[1]{
    \write\logFile{#1}
}
\AtEndDocument{
    \closeout\logFile
}

\writeToLog{Compiled on \today}

\begin{document}

\today

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the datetime2 package, it has expandable commands.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried and added the result to the question as the edit. Would you please check again?

Comment: load the english module with `\usepackage[calc,en-GB]{datetime2}`, and then use `\DTMenglishmonthname`.  And don't use `\,`, that is not expandable either.